# Esper: time_batch unsing timestamp attribute of event-POJO

Tags: esper

I've got a very specific, but short question on esper. I get event-POJOs in esper, which all come with their timeStamp as attribute. I need to do a time_batch window, but i have to do the windowing according to the the timestamps of the events. The timestamp will be a long value.

I am searching the internet now for several hours and couldn't find anything that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Use external time and have the timestamps be the source of time. This is described in http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.0.1/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#api-controlling-time

For example.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setInternalTimerEnabled(false);
EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);
....
epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new CurrentTimeSpanEvent(event.getTimestamp());
epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(event);
```